# Python subprocess using import subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

Can this be somehow overcome? Can a child process create a subprocess?

The problem is, I have a ready application which needs to call a Python script. This script on its own works perfectly, but it needs to call existing shell scripts.

Schematically the problem is in the following code:

#### parent.py

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['/usr/sfw/bin/python', '/usr/apps/openet/bmsystest/relAuto/variousSW/child.py','1', '2'])
```

#### child.py

```
import sys
import subprocess
print sys.argv[0]
print sys.argv[1]

subprocess.call(['ls -l'], shell=True)
exit
```

#### Running child.py

```
python child.py 1 2
  all is ok
```

#### Running parent.py

```
python  parent.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/apps/openet/bmsystest/relAuto/variousSW/child.py", line 2, in ?
    import subprocess
ImportError: No module named subprocess
```

Comment: This is on Solaris 2.6.2 - did you try these examples on a different platform?

Comment: Sorry - Solaris 10, python 2.6.2 was built ffrom the source

Comment: It should work. See my answer. I have a hunch that you are using two different python executable.

Comment: Just before the `import subprocess` line in child.py, try printing `sys.path`. Compare between the case where it works and the case where it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

> There should be nothing stopping you from using subprocess in both child.py and parent.py

I am able to run it perfectly fine. :)

**Issue Debugging**:

> You are using `python` and `/usr/sfw/bin/python`.

1. Is bare python pointing to the same python?
2. Can you check by typing 'which python'?

I am sure if you did the following, it will work for you.

```
/usr/sfw/bin/python parent.py
```

Alternatively, Can you change your `parent.py code` to

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['python', '/usr/apps/openet/bmsystest/relAuto/variousSW/child.py','1', '2'])
```

Comment: I'm assuming the problem is the module search path, as opposed to the code itself. So yeah, answer forthcoming. :)

Comment: yes, I am using the same python  which python
/usr/sfw/bin/python

Comment: the same failure with  /usr/sfw/bin/python   parent.py

Comment: no,  python   parent.py
subproc call ..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/apps/openet/bmsystest/relAuto/variousSW/child.py", line 2, in ?
    import subprocess
ImportError: No module named subprocess

Answer (score 0):

Using `subprocess.call` is not the proper way to do it. In my view, `subprocess.Popen` would be better.

parent.py:

```
1 import subprocess
2 
3 process = subprocess.Popen(['python', './child.py', 'arg1', 'arg2'],\
4         stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,\
5         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
6 process.wait()
7 print process.stdout.read()
```

child.py

```
1 import subprocess
2 import sys
3 
4 print sys.argv[1:]
5 
6 process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
7 
8 process.wait()
9 print process.stdout.read()
```

Out of program:

```
python parent.py 
['arg1', 'arg2']
.
..
chid.py
child.py
.child.py.swp
parent.py
.ropeproject
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add your python directory to sys.path in chield.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
```

Yes, it's bad way, but it can help you.